# How to add some php code in header.php using plugin

Tags: themes, theme-options, headers

is there any way to add some php code on top in header.php file, i want to add ob_start(); function in my theme header.php file using plugin.

i used the following code but it not working

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function(){ 
echo "<?php ob_start(); ?>"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like just syntax:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function(){ 
    ob_start();
}
```

Comment: This code is not working on live, only work on localhost @Aniruddha

Comment: This is something to do with PHP settings on your live. Make sure your output buffering is on. I would suggest to go through documentation of `ob_start()`